# Magento 2 REST API - get product by slug, or get media in REST search

Tags: rest, magento, magento2

I have an ember app which I'm using as the front end. I need to fetch a product from the REST api but instead of using the SKU, I need to use the slug. So I access the following endpoint which works fine: `http://*.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=url_key&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=daniels-icecream-slug`

However, the result is obviously a product list as opposed to the product endpoint, so some of the data is omitted. Namely, the `media_gallery_entries` field. So is there anyways I can either return this data in the `/products?searchCriteria` endpoint or is there a way I can fetch `/products/:slug` instead of `/products/:sku` for the product endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

you need to define conditionType as well with the API Call like following

```
V1/products/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=url_key&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%shirt%&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

> Parameters :

```
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=url_key
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%shirt%
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

**Note**: Make sure to prefix & suffix `%` in value as per your requirements.

I am using the same in my api Calls and it works

Comment: So this will return all the product fields like fetching an individual product?

Comment: it will return collection of products matching that url_key

Comment: that doesn't answer my question - I need to get the `media_gallery_entries` data object on the product and I need to obtain the product by product_slug. `/products/` omits the `media_gallery_entries` field, however `/products/:sku` retrieves it. I need to get the same data set back and fetch the product from the slug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Magento v2.2, and when I do a search, each item has a `image` attribute (in the `custom_attributes` list) that mangento automatically adds to a product when up add an image to it:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "sku": "MH07-XS-Black",
    "name": "Hero Hoodie-XS-Black",
    "custom_attributes": [{
        "attribute_code": "description",
        "value": "<p>Gray and black color blocking sets you apart as the Hero Hoodie keeps you warm on the bus, campus or cold mean streets. Slanted outsize front pockets keep your style real . . . convenient.</p>\n<p>&bull; Full-zip gray and black hoodie.<br />&bull; Ribbed hem.<br />&bull; Standard fit.<br />&bull; Drawcord hood cinch.<br />&bull; Water-resistant coating.</p>"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "image",
        "value": "/m/h/mh07-black_main.jpg"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "small_image",
        "value": "/m/h/mh07-black_main.jpg"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
        "value": "/m/h/mh07-black_main.jpg"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "color",
        "value": "49"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "minimal_price",
        "value": "54.0000"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "category_ids",
        "value": [
          "15"
        ]
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "options_container",
        "value": "container2"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "required_options",
        "value": "0"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "has_options",
        "value": "0"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "url_key",
        "value": "hero-hoodie-xs-black"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
        "value": "0"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
        "value": "2"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code": "size",
        "value": "167"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```